# mqtt on Laravel with PHP

Tags: php, laravel, raspberry-pi, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm using the MQTT on my raspberry and on my Ubuntu. I use terminal for start subscriber and publisher and it works so good. But now I want to create a website (using laravel) with this features. I googled it, but I don't find anything interesting. Is it possible to do and how?

Comment: Do you want to create publisher & Subscriber from Website ?

Comment: yes, I need it for Website, I can storage the messages in a Database

Answer (score 4):

Unlike with HTTP, MQTT is typically used by opening a long-running connection between an application process and a MQTT server.

While it is perfectly possible to open a connection, publish a single message and then close the socket again, it doesn't really work for subscribing to a stream of messages.

PHP's typically mode of operation is to start a process, wait for an HTTP connection, handle the request and then start a new process. This doesn't fit well with the typical MQTT mode of having a long-running process.

This had started to change with people using the PHP built-in HTTP server. I am not sure if Laravel provides a mechanism to keep variables/TCP connections in place between handling requests.

Alternatively it is possible to subscribe to a MQTT topic in a long-running CLI PHP script and persisting it locally (for example a database, KV store, memcache, redis) and then serving the data from the datastore.

It depends a lot on what you are trying to achieve.