# Keep a MQTT Client Connection always active

Tags: php, client, publish-subscribe, mqtt, phpmqtt

I am using `CloudMQTT` as a `MQTT broker` in my Pub-Sub based application. I am using my `publisher` to publish data to the `CloudMQTT server` over a `topic`, and I plan to `subscribe` to the broker on my webpage to recieve the transmitted information.

I am using this procedure to create a `Client`(subscriber): https://www.cloudmqtt.com/docs-php.html

Code goes as follows:

```
// subscribe.php
require("phpMQTT.php");

$host = "hostname"; 
$port = port;
$username = "username"; 
$password = "password"; 

$mqtt = new phpMQTT($host, $port, "ClientID".rand()); 

if(!$mqtt->connect(true,NULL,$username,$password)){
  exit(1);
}

//currently subscribed topics
$topics['topic'] = array("qos"=>0, "function"=>"procmsg");
$mqtt->subscribe($topics,0);

while($mqtt->proc()){        
}

$mqtt->close();
function procmsg($topic,$msg){
  echo "Msg Recieved: $msg";
}
```

Here is the `phpMQTT.php` file: https://github.com/bluerhinos/phpMQTT/blob/master/phpMQTT.php

However, the issue in this case is that it recieves data only when the webpage is open.. I want to keep the connection alive even if the webpage is not open to always recieve published messages, how can I do it?

**EDIT :** I might be open to using some other technology on the server to handle this subscription process, if anyone can recommend some alternatives

Comment: you can't while running under a webserver. you'd have to run it as a CLI app, or `fork` a copy so it keeps running independently of the server.

Comment: Do you have any resource or link from where I want to see it? I would actually like to keep the script from CLI going too, so that in case the process is terminated, it starts back up automatically

Comment: Similar question to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39777533/mqtt-on-laravel-with-php/39791844#39791844

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's typically mode of operation is to start a process, wait for an HTTP connection, handle the request and then start a new process. This doesn't fit well with the typical MQTT mode of having a long-running process; hence closing the MQTT connection when you close the web page.

It is possible to subscribe to a MQTT topic in a long-running CLI PHP script, but you will have to have some other mechanism to keep the process running. There are a lot of different ways of doing this, depending on your preferences and operating system:

- a script started using /etc/rc.local at system startup
- using a init.d script
- using a process manager, such as DJB's daemontools or runit
- If you are using Ubuntu, then upstart is a popular mechanism

Searching stackoverflow finds the following related question and several answers:

- [Run php script as daemon process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036654/run-php-script-as-daemon-process)

Comment: Just wondering, considering the MQTT architecture, which programing language architecture would work best with MQTT then if you have any suggestions?

Comment: NodeJS and Express?

Comment: Thanks mate! I configured it using upstart and the cli!